# php - search form with drop down

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a basic advanced search with an input which will then search through any results that have a matching category field that is selected in the dropdown and then also a matching keyword field for company_name in "advancedSearch". I have gotten to the stage where I can use the drop down to then display the matching data but I’m having trouble querying that with the search input.

Here is my form code from index.php

```
<form action="advanced-search.php" method="POST">   
    <input id="advancedInput" placeholder="Advanced Search" type="search" name="advancedSearch"> 

    <?php 
        $sqlSelect="SELECT category FROM categories";
        $result = $db -> query ($sqlSelect);

        echo "<select id=\"selectAdvanced\" name=\"value\">"; 
        echo "<option></option>";

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            print "<option value='" . $row['category'] . "'>" . $row['category'] . "</option>";
        }

        echo "</select>";
    ?>

    <input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
```

And here is the code from my advanced-search.php

```
<?php    

if(isset($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['value'])) {

    $username = trim(strip_tags($_POST['value']));

    include('dbConfig.php');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Can't connect: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $where = ($username == "category")? "" : " WHERE category = '$username'";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM company_listings" . $where; // Create Query 

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);  // Run Query

    echo "<table border=1><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>created</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .  $row['company_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['created'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";    
    }

    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

This code works great for echoing out the matching categories from the dropdown but I cant work out how I would further query the search from the "advanced search" input.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "basic advanced search"... :-)

Comment: This code looks like it works. Which bit are you saying doesn’t work? What would you try and do next?

Comment: BTW, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. Just because your GUI is restricting the values via a dropdown doesn't mean someone can't bypass that and attack the server directly.

Comment: `I cant work out how I would further query the search from the "advanced search" input.` I really don't know what you mean by this, it's a bit vague. Are you asking how to add more fields to your search? Perhaps give us an example of what you want to do, and what you've tried so far to achieve it.

Comment: I am only getting the results from the drop down I would like those queried against search input. I hope that makes sense. Thanks again. Also yes I am aware I will be looking into this thanyou for the advice @ADyson.

Comment: No it doesn't make sense. Whatever you select in the dropdown, it will look in the database for rows where the "category" field matches the "value" field in the option chosen in the dropdown. Then it displays those results on the screen in a table. What else did you want / expect to happen? Or are you saying that it is not displaying the results? The terminology you're using to describe the situation is very unclear.

Comment: At the moment when I hit submit the form returns all the matching results for the category from the dropdown. So say I search "google" and select "technology" from the drop down I will get all the results with the category "technology" rather than the results with the "google" keyword + the category "technology". Sorry if that was a tad confusing i hope that has cleared it up.

Comment: Well you're not using the value of the "advancedSearch" field anywhere in your PHP, so it's not very surprising. I assume you want to search inside one or more of your other fields for items which match (or maybe partially match) the value in that field? State the requirement clearly and precisely. And...do you know about adding multiple clauses to a WHERE statement in SQL using AND and OR? Because that's basically the guts of the solution.

Comment: Yes im trying to work out what the next step would be and yes I would like the "advancedSearch" to search the dropdown results.

Comment: Like I said though, which database fields should it be searching in? And should it be an exact match on the field, or just where the field contains that value (but maybe some other text too)? This is what I mean by the requirement not being precise. I assume you must know exactly what search you want to do, so tell us as well. Right not your requirement is not implementable because it's too vague. P.S. calling it "search the dropdown results" is a bit confusing. You're not searching any results, you're searching the database. The results are the output of the search, not the input.

Comment: It should be searching the category field. Yes I knew I was getting confused somewhere I have been looking at this for to long. Yes it should be an exact math on that field.

Comment: Searching the same field from two different inputs is a bad idea. This will really confuse the users. I can't see any advantage in that. Are you sure that's what you want? Are you sure that's what you mean? Should it not be that you type word e.g. "google", and select a category e.g. "technology" and it maybe finds all rows where the category is "technology" AND one of the other fields (e.g. maybe company name) contains "google". Surely that's what you mean? In which case the "advancedSearch" field value should be used to search the company name field, not the category field.

Comment: You would be using the search input "advancedSearch" to query where the category which is chosen by "selectAdvanced".

Comment: "You would be using the search input "advancedSearch" to query where the category which is chosen by "selectAdvanced" "...yes but to query **what**? Restricting it again by the category field makes no sense. The user already restricted it via the dropdown. They don't want to restrict it again via the textbox. Besides, if the values don't match exactly there would be no results. I don't know if we're having a language barrier here or you are struggling conceptually with this, it's hard to tell. But you are still being very unclear about your requirement.

Comment: Yes sorry you would be searching for keywords like google etc. in the company_name field. I believe I have worn myself out today apologies.

Comment: Ok, finally we've got it. So to go back to my earlier question...do you know about adding multiple clauses to a WHERE statement in SQL using AND and OR? Because that's basically the core of the solution.

Comment: Yes so I would be adding AND and OR to my existing statement?

Comment: Yes exactly. But only add it if a value was entered in the advancedSearch textbox. And you probably want an AND , since you want to restrict the results by both fields simultaneously. Maybe try it directly in SQL first.

Comment: Thankyou for being patient with me I think this has given me good groundwork to get started tomorrow and I will run some sql queires first. I will edit when I have worked this out but I will mark as answered as you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out that using AND in my query like this and using the Request on submit I was able to get what I was after... Thanks to @ADyson for the nudge. I have added my updated advanced-search.php file below;

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

$username = (($_POST['value']));

$advanced = (($_POST['advancedSearch']));

include('dbConfig.php');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Can't connect: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sql=" SELECT * FROM company_listings WHERE company_name like '%".$advanced."%' AND category LIKE '%".$username."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);  // Run Query

echo "<table border=1><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>created</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .  $row['company_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['created'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";    
}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```